# fixing incompatible types error in R using dplyr/mutate

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr

I'm trying to use the tidyverse/dplyr package in R to work with data including vectorized calls to an online API (from Altmetric) to add rows using mutate.

The smallest code I can create that reproduces the error is that below.  I get the error "Error: incompatible types, expecting a numeric vector"

```
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)

fromJSON_wrapper <- function(x,y) {
  fromJSON(x)[[c(y)]]
}

toy <- tibble(
      doi = c("10.1002/anie.201500251", "10.1080/19443994.2015.1005695", "10.1007/s13721-015-0095-0"), 
      url = c("https://api.altmetric.com/v1/doi/10.1002/anie.201500251", "https://api.altmetric.com/v1/doi/10.1080/19443994.2015.1005695", "https://api.altmetric.com/v1/doi/10.1080/19443994.2015.1005695")
      )

extracted <- toy %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(score = fromJSON_wrapper(url,"score"))
```

The code for extracting a single score below works, whether just using the wrapper or on a one row tibble and I'm not sure why my code isn't working.

```
fromJSON_wrapper("https://api.altmetric.com/v1/doi/10.1007/s13721-015-0095-0")
extracted <- toy[1,] %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(score = fromJSON_wrapper(url, "score"))
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Using `as.numeric(fromJSON(x)[[c(y)]])` would work. The problem is that sometimes the function return a numeric value, and other times returns an integer. It doesn't seem like `dplyr` likes to combine those into a numeric column.

Answer (score 3):

It's simpler to just iterate over the vector of URLs and extract what you need. `purrr::map_dbl` makes this simple, though `sapply` would work fine, too.

```r
library(tidyverse)

toy <- tibble(
    doi = c("10.1002/anie.201500251", "10.1080/19443994.2015.1005695", "10.1007/s13721-015-0095-0"), 
    url = c("https://api.altmetric.com/v1/doi/10.1002/anie.201500251", "https://api.altmetric.com/v1/doi/10.1080/19443994.2015.1005695", "https://api.altmetric.com/v1/doi/10.1080/19443994.2015.1005695")
)

extracted <- toy %>% mutate(score = map_dbl(url, ~jsonlite::fromJSON(.x)$score))

extracted %>% select(doi, score)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>                             doi score
#>                           <chr> <dbl>
#> 1        10.1002/anie.201500251  0.25
#> 2 10.1080/19443994.2015.1005695  1.00
#> 3     10.1007/s13721-015-0095-0  1.00
```

Comment: Thanks alistaire, I knew there should be an easy way to do it!

Comment: I was wondering if there's an easy way to take all of the data returned by fromJSON and flatten it into a series of columns in the dataframe depending on the names in the list.  Something like:list_df <- toy %>% mutate(json_data = map(url, ~jsonlite::fromJSON(.x))) followed by df2 <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(list_df$json_data), nrow=3, byrow=T),stringsAsFactors = F) (this code doesn't work as each row of json_data has a variable length with a different subset of named elements.

Comment: You can simplify grabbing it with just `toy <- toy %>% mutate(json_data = map(url, jsonlite::fromJSON))` and extract pieces at will, but if the response isn't standardized and lengths vary, there's not an obvious data.frame structure to which to convert the whole thing. You could get something with `toy %>% mutate(json_df = map(json_data, ~.x %>% map(list) %>% as_data_frame)) %>% unnest(json_df)`, but you'll end up with a lot of messy list columns.